# how to ignore character "\" if this is in a dropdownlist c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dropdownlistfor

I am building an application on c# visual studio for a web page. I have in a dropdownlist in C# a item "soporte\andres" but when i take that value i have "soporte\andres"

This is the image about what i have in a dropdownlist:
[image]

but doing a debug i have this value in a variable:
[image]

What can I do to get the exact value I need `("soporte\andres")` ?
I tried to use `@dropwdownlist.value` but this doesn´t work. Visual Studio continues changing `"\"` for `"\\"`.

Comment: The debugger always shows escaped characters in strings with the escaping character (a leading backslash).  So, a string like [domain\user] will show up in the debugger as "domain\\user".  If you pull down the menu from the little down arrow to the right of the magnifying glass and pick the text viewer, you will see the string as text, and the escaping character won't be there.

Comment: If you say `var myString = "soporte\\andres";` or `var myString = @"soporte\andres";` you will end up with the same string.  It will be [soporte\andres] (I'm using the brackets to "bracket" the string) but will be rendered as "soporte\\andres" in the debugger and `soporte\andres` in the debugger's text viewer

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. that is correct!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code, but in general, you would do something like this:

```
string a = @"soporte\andres";
```